# SecurityException: Calling from not trusted UID

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, uid

I get below error in my [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) account, and try to find solution of this error, but didn't get any success.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Calling from not trusted UID!
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3249)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.finishInstrumentation(ActivityThread.java:4706)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.finish(Instrumentation.java:201)
       at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.finish(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:334)
       at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.finish(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:405)
       at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:394)
       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1738)
```

I don't understand this **warning or error**.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I got the same error on older Android (4.x) since I enabled Firebase A/B testing on my apps. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: after few time i forgot this i will looking it this and update you

Comment: @muratiakos Remove android.support.test.runner from my project and not getting this error again but this not right solution.

Comment: Seeing this on Android 4.3 Galaxy S3 ?

Comment: I get Same on Android 4.3 Galaxy S3.. Any solution

Comment: Remove android.support.test.runner.. as of now not find any solution

Comment: related [Calling from not trusted UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360801/calling-from-not-trusted-uid)

Comment: In our case this exception occurred 20 minutes after uploading a new version to the Play Store. It was initiated by an Android 4.3 Galaxy S3, which also tested some forms and dialogs in our app. That's a test device from Google, so we ignored the exception.