# Calling from not trusted UID

Tags: java, android, testing, android-uiautomator

When I was running UIAutomator in Android Studio, a crash shows sometimes.

```
 W/ActivityManager: Crash of app com.example.testsample running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.example.testsample.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
07-16 19:19:34.191 7834-7850/? W/Binder: Binder call failed.
java.lang.SecurityException: Calling from not trusted UID!
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection.throwIfCalledByNotTrustedUidLocked(UiAutomationConnection.java:427)
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection.shutdown(UiAutomationConnection.java:324)
    at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub.onTransact(IUiAutomationConnection.java:209)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
```

But it didn't shows every time. I can run successfully when this not showed.
Can Anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: I've tried the same code in another device(HUAWEI Mate9) and it works well. Never shows this error. So it may be only cause in specific device(for me it's MeiTu T8).

Comment: This error shows when running. Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

Comment: related [SecurityException: Calling from not trusted UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498262/securityexception-calling-from-not-trusted-uid)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void throwIfCalledByNotTrustedUidLocked() {
    final int callingUid = Binder.getCallingUid();
    if (callingUid != mOwningUid && mOwningUid != Process.SYSTEM_UID
            && callingUid != 0 /*root*/) {
        throw new SecurityException("Calling from not trusted UID!");
    }
}
```

This is the method which throws your error. Perhaps the `uid` is different than the process `uid` or the `uid` on that device is not `root`. Maybe you can add some prints in your app to find out.

Comment: I add logs before and after in every UIAutomator function calls. And this crash shows randomly. Not in a specific place.